# C# Regex remove ampersand

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following string: {}&{} and I want to remove ampersand to get {}{}. Here is my Regex.Replace call:

```
Regex.Replace(@"\{\}&\{\}", @"\}.&\{", "}{")
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: If you're simply trying to remove an ampersand... why use a regex when a more simple string.replace will be much easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the `.` doing there? That's going to match against any character, and since there is nothing between `}` and `&` it will fail to match. Try remove it:

```
Regex.Replace(@"\{\}&\{\}", @"\}&\{", "}{")
```

[See it on rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/G7UKgtPLAV)

Or make the character optional with `?`:

```
Regex.Replace(@"\{\}&\{\}", @"\}.?&\{", "}{")
```

[See it on rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/KK1tHWbmYY)

Answer (score 4):

Why complicating? why not just:

```
myString.Replace("}&{", "}{"); // replaces '}&{' with '}{'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure there is something between the ampersand and the curly bracket, but there **could** be something, add an asterisk after the period:

```
Regex.Replace(@"\{\}&\{\}", @"\}.*&\{", "}{")
/*                              ^^ here  */
```